# How to retrain mobilenet model for custom images

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, training-data

I have followed [tensorflow for poets](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0) tutorial and got a basic understanding of how to retrain a model for custom objects. In the tutorial, I retrained the model for different categories of flowers and then used the newly generated graph and got the correct results.

Now I want to retrain the model, where I have more than 500 photos of `engineers`(person) working on a construction site. For some reason, the model is not giving the correct accuracy as its only able to detect 2 persons while there are 4 persons in the frame. I thought of retraining with the photos and then use it again. Here I have few questions:

1. Do I need to label all the persons in the photos.
2. Photos also consist of vehicles like truck, so should I also label the vehicles and create another data set to train.
3. How to label images. I used this [label image](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg), it generated `xml file` but I think we need to give photos to retrain the model as described in the [tensorflow for poets](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0)

Can anyone please help me understand these concepts of retraining a model for any custom objects. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use transfer learning to train your model. i.e. you can initialise the weights of the model using some pretrained model of the mobile net and then start training from there.

as for your questions:

1. yes you should label all the persons with same class (lets say workers) in the images as the network needs to detect each person in the frame. if you don't label all the person then it might get confused as what it needs to detect because the label and unlabelled person doesn't have any distinguishing properties.
2. if you only want to detect person you need not label trucks/trains/vehicles in your image.
3. you can label images using the `xml` file or json file doesnt matter. but the way you annonate your image should be familliar to you as you would need to send those data to the network. people often use the xml format as each xml corresponds to each image and inside each xml each tags defined the object that to be located inside that image with there respective coordinates and classes.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am labelling the images as of now. Will update you onece done.

Comment: ok accept and upvote the answer if you found it help full and update me if you got stuck.